# Is it OK to replace a method by a plain function?

Tags: python

This works as expected, but I am somehow unsure about this approach. Is it safe? Is it pythonic?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        if parameter == 0:
            # trivial case, the result is always zero
            self.calc = lambda x: 0.0  # <== replacing a method
        self._parameter = parameter

    def calc(self, x):
        # ... long calculation of result ...
        return result
```

(If there is any difference between Python2 and Python3, I'm using Python3 only.)

Comment: It is ugly, i.e. difficult to read and to debug, but it works.

Comment: A little better would be something like `if x: self.calc = self._calc else: self.calc = lambda...`

Comment: It's safe as long as it isn't a special method (i.e. `__xxx__`) which are always looked up based on the type of the object (its class), not individual instances. Use in moderation because it's not very Pythonic.

Comment: @zvone I like your suggestion

Answer (score 4):

This is very confusing. If someone else reads it, they won't understand what is going on. Just put a `if` statement at the beginning of your method.

```
def calc(self, x):
    if self.parameter == 0:
         return 0
    # ... long calculation of result ...
    return result
```

Also if you change `self.parameter` after it was initialized with `0`, your function wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: I do agree with the confusing. Please excuse that I will not pick a particular answer to accept, because there is a good point in each answer and comments as well I got so far

Answer (score 3):

You'll have a problem should `parameter` ever changes, so I don't consider it good practice.
Instead, I think you should do this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self._parameter = parameter

    def calc(self, x):
        if not self._parameter:
            return 0.0
        # ... long calculation of result ...
        return result
```

Comment: Please excuse that I will not pick a particular answer to accept, because there is a good point in each answer and in comments as well I got so far

Answer (score 0):

*I decided to post a summary of several comments and answers. Please do not vote for this summary, but give +1 to the original authors instead*.

- the approach is safe except for special `__methods__`
- the approach is deemed unpythonic, undesirable, or unnecessary etc.
- the parameter determining the function to use must be constant. If it is not the case, this approach makes no sense at all.
- from several suggestions I prefer the code below for general cases and the obvious `if cond: return 0.0` for simple cases:

---

```
 class Example:
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        if parameter == 0:
            self.calc = self._calc_trivial
        else:
            # ... pre-compute data if necessary ...
            self.calc = self._calc_regular
        self._parameter = parameter

    def _calc_regular(self, x):
        # ... long calculation of result ...
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def _calc_trivial(x):
       return 0.0
```

Comment: This is un-Pythonic because it's really not necessary. True, it _is_ slightly more efficient to do this rather than testing `._parameter` each time you call `.calc`, but the relative speed difference is tiny (unless `._calc_regular` is itself trivial). IOW, this optimization makes minimal improvement to the code's efficiency at the expense of making the code more complicated to read and to maintain. Also, as others have mentioned, it won't behave as expected if `._parameter` changes to or from zero after the instance has been created.

Comment: @PM2Ring: If _parameter would be allowed to change, the whole point of selecting the right function only once is lost. I will update the summary.

Comment: Sure. However, there's no way to actually prevent `._parameter` from being changed; OTOH, the leading underscore in the attribute name advises anyone using this class that it's a Bad Idea for their code to directly manipulate that attribute.